# Counter variable is printing a number less than 10 000 sometimes

Tags: java, multithreading, synchronization

When I run the code, `System.out.println(counter);` prints a number LESS than 10 000 sometimes. Before running the code, I thought that counter should be between [10 000, 20 000] depending on if the OS schedular decides to execute the main thread and t1 on seperate cores or in the same core by switching between them or a combination of both.

```
public class App  {
    private  static int counter = 0;

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Thread t1 = new Thread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                for(int i = 0; i < 10_000; i++) {
                    counter++;
                }
            }
        });

        t1.start();

        for(int i = 0; i < 10_000; i++) {
            counter++;
        }
        System.out.println(counter); // *****

    }
}
```

I believe the reason can be explained by this logic (I'm not sure if I'm correct though)

1. The OS schedular decides t1 to be executed for lets say 0.1 ms and for that period of time, counter = 567 **BUT when t1 has read the value of counter (that is the next step was to increment counter by 1**, the executing of t1 stopped ( because 0.1 ms has passed).
2. Then the main thread is being executed for let's say 1 ms. And for that period of time, counter = 5699 **BUT unlike t1, the execution of the main thread stopped directly after the main thread incremented the counter variable.**
3. Then t1 is executed BUT NOTE... because t1 stopped its first executions **AFTER READING THE COUNTER VARIABLE, the t1 variable will use the value of what it read at step 1**. that is 567. Then let's say that t1 increments counter from 567 to 3056.
4. **NOTE BECAUSE MAIN DIDNT READ THE COUNTER VARIABLE AT STEP 2.** THEN,THE MAIN THREAD WILL USE WHATEVER COUNTER IS EQUAL TO RIGHT NOW, WHICH IS 3056 ( even though counter at step 2. was a bigger number, 5699.) and hence this explains the logic of why my program sometimes prints a number LESS than 10 000.

Can my explanation be a reason of why the code sometimes prints number less than 10 000? And can the program print a number BIGGER than 20 000 ? ( because I believe the answer is yes because of similar logic above ( I have executed the program a lot of times but I haven't seen the console printing a number bigger than 20 000).

Comment: Effectively, the number can't be larger than 20k, but in general, the behaviour is undefined because there is no synchronization.

Comment: The number can be smaller than 10k because the printed value is overriden by the other thread with any possible value of its local copy.

Comment: So, was my explanation of why the number can be less than 10k right ? and btw how do you know for sure that the number can't be greater than 20k ?

Comment: I don't read it cuz I'm lazy but anyways, the explanation in general is, the other thread can write its value at any time, as there is no synchronization. In more complex examples/programs, you won't be able to come up with some step-by-step explanation, so you should instead prefer to identify missing synchronization. The number can't be greater than 20k cuz there are 20k increments in total. I'm not aware what kind of hardware/logic could yield 20k+, but, as I wrote, it's undefined so anything can happen. I think the Java spec has no rules to follow here.

Answer (score 6):

> Can my explanation be a reason of why the code sometimes prints number less than 10 000?

No.

> And for that period of time, counter = 5699

There's your problem in your thinking.

There isn't 'the value of `counter`'. That's not a thing.

There's 'the value of one of the many many clones of that field'.

The relevant documentation/spec is the [Java Memory Model (JMM)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_memory_model) (See *The Java Memory Model* section (§17.4) described in the [*Java Language Specification*](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se21/html/jls-17.html#jls-17.4)). It explains that a [Java Virtual Machine (JVM)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_virtual_machine) implementation has many choices, and the  burden is on the Java programmer to write code so that it works regardless of what choice a JVM makes).

The specific rules set out in the JMM involve observability. It defines the following conditions:

- Observability explicitly does not cover timing. If you can 'observe' that thing A must have ran before thing B based solely on timers and how long things take, that is *not* a violation of a rule 'the JVM must ensure A cannot be observed before B'. Because where the JMM talks about 'observing', timing doesn't count.
- All rules in the JMM are in the form of: "A JVM implementation must guarantee X". Almost all of those are in the form of: "When executing bytecode A, the JVM [must / must not / can go either way on] whether that can observe any changes made to any fields by bytecode B". The default behaviour is 'can go either way on'. The JMM enumerates exactly where an ordering must exist in observability, and everything not on the list therefore means: "Whatever - you might observe the change made by A, you might not - if your code depends on whether it does or not, your code is broken. In a way that is really hard to test, so, ouch".

The JVM **makes full use of the rights it has gained under the JMM**. It's not **just** about which statement 'runs before another' or even whether any updates one thread makes are synchronized to another thread. It's even about the JVM flat out reordering.

That list is generally called the 'Happens Before' list, because the terminology used by the JMM is 'happens before'. Here's the most relevant parts of that list:

- The in-thread 'natural' HB: HB(A, B) is established if A and B run in the same thread, and as per execution rules, A comes before B. This is the 'duh, obviously' rule. Given: `x = 5; x = 10; y = x;` it is illegal for a JVM to reorder that `x = 5;` and `x = 10;` such that `y` is now 5. However, it's **just about observability**. Thus, given: `x = 5; y = 10;` the JVM is free to generate optimized machine code for `x = 5; y = 10;` that first sets y and afterwards sets x. It actually does that sometimes, to optimize CPU pipelining. It doesn't mean a JVM will always do that, or will ever do that - it just means that *if* a JVM implementation does that, there's nothing wrong with it. And *some* do. A JVM doesn't even have to be consistent; it may do it now, and tomorrow it won't: It's not just to mess with you either, a JVM will for example track which way a branch (an `if`) has gone in recent executions, and when hotspotting out the machine code, will use this to write a branch predicted loop (in machine code, there is no while or if, there's (conditional) `GOTO` (JMP). Jumping tends to be slower as CPUs 'look ahead' and pre-process upcoming instructions, which is pointless if you jump. A branch predicted loop or if is one where the machine code does not jump for the most common path. If 'recent executions' are slightly different, the JVM might generate the different branch predicted code, and from that divergence, anything can happen.
- Thread ops HB: `HB(t.start(), run)` is established where `t.start()` is code that starts a thread, and `run` is the first line in the `run()` method of that thread. Similarly, `HB(end, join)` is defined: A thread's final line of code happens before `t.join()` on that thread returning.
- `synchronized`: There exists an order that threads go through synchronized blocks on the same monitor, i.e. if one thread has `synchronized (x) {}` and another thread also has that code (where x points at the same object), you can list exactly in which order the threads entered these blocks. `HB(end, start)` is established, where 'end' is the final line in the synchonized block of the thread that went through first, and 'start' is the first line in the synchronized block of the thread that went through last. Similar rules exist about accessing `volatile` variables, but generally it's a lot harder to figure out which one is the 'before' and which one is the 'after' when `volatile` is involved.

There are a few more. It is important to realize that loads of `java.*` API calls establish HB. **For example, attempting to witness this stuff in action by emitting a bunch of `System.out.println` statements just befuddles you because that established all sorts of HB that messes up any attempt to reproduce some race condition**. This stuff is rocket science.

The above is a simplification, but a fairly accurate one, of the JMM. What this boils down to in practice is 2 things:

- Reordering. The JVM will just do stuff out of order. As long as the code it jumbles around is not observing each other's effects the JVM is allowed to do this.
- Var caching. CPUs these days can't even read main memory. At all. The only thing they can do, is read from local cache (which is on-die, i.e. each die has its own cache), and send a message to the memory controller to flush out an entire page's worth (64k or more, pages are big) back to main memory, and then load in an entire page's worth in the now free cache page, and then go to sleep for 500 to 1500 cycles because it takes a while for the memory controller to do this. Naturally then, 'just write it all back to main memory' is **ridiculously, incredibly slow** because it's 1500 cycles **every time** you read or write. Hence, obviously then, to keep things speedy, each CPU core will just read and write to some slot inside one of its on-die cache pages, and **effectively that means that usually each field being actively written to/read from in a thread is a 'copy' and all these copies are independent**, with no idea which 'copy' ends up 'winning' once these threads end. One of the copies 'wins' and ends up in main memory. Eventually.

### So what's with the sub-10000 result?

1. Thread T1 starts out seeing '0' for that field and loops 2500 times. **Its clone** is now 2500. The main memory value is still 0. This is an efficiency core.
2. Whilst that is going on, Thread M (Main) now picks up the ball and runs for 5000 times, its counter is now 5000. It's faster than T1 because its a power core.
3. The CPUs are overheating a tad or simply for general battery saving purposes, main is pre-empted, and that core is just put to sleep for a bit. On this architecture, that means the on-die caches are lost, so they are flushed to disk. main memory `count` is now `5000`.
4. Your music player needs to decode a bunch more of the MP3 because it has run out. Your OS pre-empts T1 (so that's why it stopped at 2500 times in the loop), and uses it to decode some MP3. During this process, T1's cache page with the counter in it gets flushed to main memory, so main mem now has `counter = 2500` in it.
5. the MP3 decoding is done and T1 is picked back up, and races all the way to the end, is done, and flushes its value back to main memory.
6. Right before that flushing happens, `M` gets a core and needs to load `counter` from main memory, and it gets in just before T1 writes out, so it loads in 2500. Immediately afterwards, T1 writes its 10000 in.
7. M runs its remaining 5000 loops, now its copy of `counter` is 7500. It's done, so writes that back to memory.

Tada: Less than 10k is in there.

**WARNING**: That story is fictional. The point is not that all CPU hardware works that way. The point is: That is [A] a plausible story (CPUs do kinda work that way), and [B] Nothing in that story violates the JMM spec.

"Why did this happen" is not generally answerable for java code, because java runs on a vast array of hardware with nearly as vast an array of how things work. That's why you have to go back to the JMM: What is a JVM **allowed** to do? Can you come up with a a way a JVM can execute your code that sticks to guarantees set forth in the JMM and results in your code not doing what you want? If the answer is 'yes', then **your code is just plain broken**, and it is not relevant that you cannot manage to find a combination of architecture, OS, and system load to actually cause an issue: **Your code is broken**, if you continue with it, one day it'll fail, and it'll be your fault. That day may never arrive until it runs on entirely new hardware (say, an [ARM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ARM_architecture_family) [Mac](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mac_(computer)#Apple_silicon_transition), quite different [architecture](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Instruction_set_architecture) if all you've tested your code on is Intel chips), or even a new [JDK](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_Development_Kit) version.